# Pasar de Codigos ASCII por Numeros en C

Tags: c, ascii

Tengo una duda con un ejercicio estoy haciendo: Tienes que pedir los numeros (codigos) del ASCII `Dame los numeros: 72,108, 112, 97` Y a la hora de que lo imprima, este te arroje en pantalla los caracteres que pertenencen `Los Caracteres son: Hola`

Esto es lo que lo que he hecho:

```
int main(void){
char c[25];
int i;

puts("Por favor ingresa el texto que deseas mostrar:");
scanf("%25s", c); 

for (i = 0; c[i] != '\0'; i++)
    printf(" %d", c[i]);

putchar('\n');

return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, esto hace lo contrario (tu pones la cadena y esta te dice los numeros)

```
Ingresa la cadena: Hola

El resultado es: 72 108 112 97
```

¿Alguna manera para hacerlo de manera inversa? o ¿se debe castear?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta ... ¿ Quieres saber como obtener el código ASCII de un caracter ? ¿ O como mostrar el caracter dado un código ?

Comment: Mas que nada, que uno ingrese los codigos del ASCII y se imprima el caracter correspondiente, por ejemplo: `Se ingresa: 87 76 68` y te arroje los caracteres de ascii ` hca `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres imprimir una letra, debes pedir mostrar una letra `"%c"` no un número `"%d"`.

Ve capturando números hasta acabar los datos de entrada y muéstralos a medida que los capturas:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int letra = 0;

    puts("Pon numeros");
    //                            vvv <--- Leemos hasta que no haya más datos en el búfer
    while (scanf("%d", &letra) != EOF)
    //           ~~~~ <--- Leemos número
        printf("%c", letra);
    //         ~~~~ <--- Mostramos letra

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[TIO](https://tio.run/##JYxLDsIgFADXcIonRgOJmuKmGq073eoVGkBL0j4aPrownh2Lbmcyo9YPpXKeW1R90gaOIWrrNt2JUosRhtYifzqrBbwpKaQ30bfQQHWglIwpBs5uDgHTYLwLTBT86mxvgAfV4p2zhWYrWP46AbMGzteLoISMftoVrSb9t6X1JiaPZf/Jud6ClBJktYN9Tb8)</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

El mecanismo a seguir podría ser:

- lees un número
- descartas un caracter (la coma)
- vuelves al primer punto

Dicho con código:

```
#define MAX_NUMEROS 10
int numeros[MAX_NUMEROS];
int total_numeros = 0;
while( total_numeros<MAX_NUMEROS )
{
  if( scanf("%d", &numeros[total_numeros]) == EOF )
    break;
  total_numeros++;
  char c = getchar(); // leemos la coma, si existe
  if( c == EOF || c == '\n')
    break; 
}

for( int i=0; i<total_numeros; i++ )
{
  printf("%c ", numeros[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Podria ser algo asi.

podrias capturar  los numeros y luego un caracter como una ",":

104 111 108 097 ,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int maximo=25;
int numeros[maximo];
int i = 0;

   printf("Enter Ints: ");

   for(; i < maximo; i++) {

      if(scanf("%d", &numeros[i]) == EOF)

         break;

   }


for (i = 0; i<25; i++)
{

     if(numeros[i] == EOF || numeros[i] <=0)
        break;
      else
    printf("%c", numeros[i]);
}

   return 0;

}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.